# How do I carry my keys, airpods, phone, wallet, and glasses?

Tags: efficiency

I have 5 things I need to carry when I head out for all but the most basic errands:

- keys to my car, office, and mailbox
- folding sunglasses (I wish I could lose these but bright sunlight hurts my eyes)
- card holder/ wallet- I just need a few IDs and a couple of cards (my office needs card access. I used to leave my wallet in my car and just carry it with me when I needed it but I have locked myself out of my office a few times as a result)
- phone (needed for music and GPS- I have a horrible sense of direction)
- airpods (the smallest set of headphones I could find- I used to be able to wrap my wired headphones around the phone until Apple decided to inflict some courage into my life)

I tried to cut down my pocket clutter to the bone, picked the most space efficient stuff I could find (pictured below). But if I wear shorts on some days, or a track suit, or dress pants, my pockets get very tight/ heavy. I don't want to switch to cargo pants, but that seems like the only realistic option.

I'd appreciate any creativity SE could muster.

[image]

Comment: You can use a belt bag, available in leather or synthetic, small or large. Or a small hand-held bag like French men use, or a small shoulder bag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also carry a lot of stuff with me always. Documents, keys, power bank, headphones ... The only solution that actually works for me is a (small) bag where I put everything. I just grab the bag when I need to go and that's it. I do not need to worry that any of the "essentials" is in some other piece of clothing and I might forget them at home.

There is a large variety of bags available. I have settled (for several years) for a bag with a long strap, and I carry it diagonally over the chest (bag on one side of the body, the strap on the shoulder on the opposite side). Mine happens to resemble a carrying bag for a tablet, but you can choose whatever you like.

I can change pants and jackets without worry, as long as I have the bag, I have everything I need.

Comment: The only other (semi-) serious suggestion I heard was to keep an extra set of keys, and headphones in all the places I frequent, but that feels like a serious security risk. I guess I'll just bite the bullet and look at getting a bag.

Comment: I totally feel you, I would not leave keys around the house just like that, like I see in the US movies.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like to carry a bag around but do wear a belt you can get a small bag attached to your belt.
These days I see a lot of phone purses in the markets, most of which seem to be aimed at women buying them, but some are in colours which are also suitable for men. Some of them only hold a phone and some flat items like cards but some are just that bit bigger which allows for keys and earpods as well.
These bags mostly come with a shoulder strap which attaches with clips or hooks, and that means that you can replace the long strap with smaller loops which go round your belt.

Or you can find a bag which has fittings for a belt already.

These bags will work as a pocket on the outside of your trousers or shorts, and as you move the pocket from one pair of bottoms to the next it is easier than big pockets.

Answer (score 0):

**How do I carry my keys, airpods, phone, wallet, and glasses?**

I carry a lot of things on my person  every day.

Being a crafty person I have many types of things to be carried on my belt or in my pockets. Personally I do not like carrying keys in my pockets as they tend to make holes in them. I have even made a mini travel pouch for when I go hiking for my feroo rod and other small items. All these are one my belt and I am hands free!

My glasses are carried in a [glasses pouch](https://www.amazon.ca/Eyeglass-Lightweight-Protective-Holster-Glasses/dp/B0785RD3NX/ref=asc_df_B0785RD3NX/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=293037087076&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=9447477443284092409&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=t&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001485&hvtargid=pla-594037657914&psc=1) as seen below.

[image]

With a little imagination, one can find many ways to carry things on one’s person. I simply like doing it the diy way.

For example a [2 Pack Faraday Bag for Key Fob](https://www.amazon.ca/Faraday-Blocking-Keyless-Shielding-Protection-Black/dp/B08QCWMTY2/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?gclid=CjwKCAiAr4GgBhBFEiwAgwORrY_ukwnQZ3PL_Lt_qIyE4tX4NrvwcB_C3XpPXzhHqFoDk5_fJApndxoCo5AQAvD_BwE&hvadid=600542474614&hvdev=t&hvlocphy=9001485&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=b&hvrand=11453725202785829165&hvtargid=kwd-469647638290&hydadcr=6791_13256391&keywords=key+fob+pouch&qid=1677796698&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyMTlZR1E4S1hKWlkxJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzA5NDMyMUU0QU04UDA1MEM2USZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUExMDM3OTc5MkoxQjhWSjM4S0kzNiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=) would do fine for your airpods.

[image]

I carryy keys with something similar to the image below, except it is made of fabric instead of leather.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a HUGE problem for men. Most of us just overstuff pockets, but that makes you look like a dumb lumpy dresser. One of my pals unloads everything in a huge gadget dump whenever he comes over. It's ridiculous.

I started using a black 1.5-inch-thick canvas 9x11 student ring binder with interior pockets and an outer zipper. It looks socially acceptable. In it I can store wallet, cell phone and charger, sunglasses, keys, and any other item necessary for the day. Keeps everything in one place zippered shut tight.

Comment: I used to joke that I miss my ex's bag more than her, just because I could leave my things in her bag lol. One of the only somewhat viable solutions I heard from a friend was to keep an extra set of keys, and headphones, etc in my office, car, and other places I frequent, but I am not comfortable leaving my keys to my house around town like that.

Answer (score 0):

My strategy is to use a phone case with a rope like this:

[image: mobile phone case with rope to hang around neck]

Then I have AirPods in a case with a clip, and I clip them onto the string. I also carry a couple of other things, and I can clip a key onto the AirPods carabiner as well. You could try something similar.